# PhpMyAdmin on Mavericks

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, osx-mavericks

I'm having a hard time trying to get PhpMyAdmin to work on Mavericks.

I have enabled PHP in apache by uncommenting the LoadModule directive in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, I have downloaded and installed MySQL 5.6.17, I have changed the root password, I have downloaded and installed PhpMyAdmin 4.1.13, but when I try to login into phpmyadmin, I'm getting the error:

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I can connect to mysql from the terminal without problem, but not from PhpMyAdmin.

Can anyone help me fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do the http servers error logs say?

Comment: Good point: I didn't think about reading the logs. Unfortunately, it says nothing at all.

Comment: I cannot really believe that. Sure you are looking at the _error_ log file? And sure you have error logging enabled _for that virtual host_?

Comment: Oh I have an error_log alright, I called a page with a phpinfo() before and there is an error line for that request:

Comment: [Fri Apr 18 11:33:39 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php on line 1

Comment: Ok, assuming that the error message you posted is what you get inside phpmyadmin then the next step is to check the permissions you granted: check from what and to what ip address phpmyadmin is trying to connect to the mysql server and compare that to the permissions you granted inside mysql. (oh, and I assume you _did_ reload the permissions inside mysql after changing them...)

Comment: In MySQL, credentials are defined by the combination of host, user and password. How did you change the root password and for which host?

Comment: Hi, I changed the root password with mysqladmin -u root password <new-password>. In the user table, root is defined for localhost, 127.0.0.1, ::1 and maurice-imac.local, all with the same password and the same privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was that I configured phpmyadmin for a tcp connection, but mysql uses Unix sockets by default.